# spring-cloud-stream-kafka: why doesn't KafkaBinderHealthIndicator cache consumers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

What's the reason for not caching `KafkaConsumer`s in `KafkaBinderHealthIndicator`? Latter is a bean created in `KafkaBinderConfiguration` autoconfig, so why not reuse the consumers?

Most likely not an issue, but feels wrong, given each node in our stack is queried 12 times a minute for `/health` by the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It never came as an issue before, but created an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/231

Potentially we could look at it for 2.0 release of Spring Cloud Stream.